# Dishwasher - pump does not stop working after getting an Error message

Tags: electrical, water, kitchens, dishwasher, pump

We have an elektrolux dishwasher which is some years old. Today while working it gave an error message about leaking water. We found no water outside on the floor.

After turning the dishwasher off the pump is still working (*without water*). We cleaned all filters and so on. We tried the reset and on/off button a few times, but nothing worked.

We tried to turn off the fuse but when turning it on again the pump again starts working. We could not turn off the fuse for too long because the fridge is on the same fuse.

The dishwasher is part of a built-in kitchen, so we could not reach the wires to disconnect the dishwasher. The users manual says to turn the device off and let it dry for some days.
Additional we will be not at home the next two days.

What is a save and not destroying way to let the dishwater rest until the serviceman comes?

Comment: It would be great to get advice, how to improve my question, instead of down-vote without comment -.-

Answer (score 1):

You can get a good extension cord  and plug the refrigerator into an outlet that is on another circuit (*fuse*), preferably one in the kitchen or not to far.

After you unplug your refrigerator let it sit unplugged for about 15 minutes before you plug it in to the other outlet. Use a good quality extension cord, not a thin cheap one,  and not to long.

Now that your refrigerator is on another circuit you can turn off the Breaker/fuse that the dishwasher is on.

Comment: good idea we will consider this, if we can not turn off the pump

Comment: Does the pump continue to run with the door left open?

Comment: yes. sadly the fridge is way built in too. we could not reach the wire until we emptied it...

Comment: @Allerleirauh - Most fridge's are on wheels so you can pull them straight out relatively easily.